# Problem starting up

Tags: gui

I'm by any means no dev or a programmer, I'm just trying to set up a Masternode following instructions. Got myself a VPS and followed [these instructions](https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-gui-installation) to install a GUI.

However, when the machine was done installing the GUI and I rebooted the system, I can view the startup process with VNC and it always stays here and doesn't start:

[image]

Can you please help me?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please pop some details here regarding your hardware and what system you had prior to trying to install the GUI. Thank you!

Comment: These are the specs of the machine:
4 vCPU Cores
10 GB RAM
700 GB HDD
100 Mbit/s Port
32 TB Traffic
Unlimited Incoming

It's running Ubuntu 20.04